# Problems with combo-box when using fx-scale javafx

Tags: javafx

As you can see in the image below the popup list-view shows towards the side and not aligned to the combo-box
[image]

This is the code I used:

```
.combo-box-popup .list-view{
-fx-scale-x: 1.1;
-fx-scale-y: 1.1;
}

.combo-box-base:showing{
-fx-scale-x: 1.1;
-fx-scale-y: 1.1;
}
```

Is there any solution? or should I just not use fx-scale?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using -fx-scale, the issue is with the initial rendering of the popup... if you close the popup and click the ComboBox again, the popup is no longer offset and displays properly... A bug was fixed for a similar issue with the list sizing for the popup initial rendering.

Comment: @b3tuning is there any way to fix this?